# JSF with Hibernate without Spring - is it the right choice?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I am going to develop a new web application of medium complexity. Right now I am somewhat comfortable with JSF and hibernate, but I have never used JSF and hibernate together before.

I just wanted to ask if it is good practice to use JSF (for both the view layer and handling business logic) and hibernate (for persistence) without Spring as a middle layer.

The reason why I am asking this is I don't know anything about the Spring framework and my customer wants development of the application to start as early as possible.

Comment: There's no need to go with Spring. As JSF and JPA (hibernate) are part of JEE standards, you could use EJB controllers and CDI for injections.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to use Hibernate. Using JSF together with CDI beans, EJB and accessing the database via JPA (in other words doing things the Java EE 7 way) just works. I've worked with both EclipseLink + JSF & Hibernate + JSF and they're basically the same.

Hibernate can sometimes cause [troubles with Lazy Initiliazation](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/four-solutions-to-lazyinitializationexc_05.html), where EclipseLink works just fine. This actually happened to me. But this issue has been already fixed from certain version, you only need to add a single property in persistence.xml.

I used EclipseLink on Glassfish and right now I am shortly using Hibernate with WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to use only JSF and Hibernate. Spring at least gives some help towards persistence and other things you might need. 
There are a lot of boilerplate have to write. This has become better with the later versions of JSF though.

But if you don't want to use Spring, take a look at [Delta Spike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/) which will provide some glue and more which makes integration a lot easier.

Comment: Delta Spike is former Seam 3 btw